# GWT. Window.Open method is not working in loops

Tags: java, gwt

I have a problem with GWT method `Window.Open`. It works normally when I want to open one window. But, when I need to open two or more URL's in a new window, it opens only one. And in a new window always shows last url in list.

```
for (RoomReservation reservetion : roomReservationListModel.getRoomReservationsList()) {
            Window.open(reservetion.getPrintoutUrl(), L10n.getMessages().print(),    HtmlCssElementNames.BLANK);
        }
```

Second param without white spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `Window.open` is window's *name*, not its title (that one is given by the document showing inside). It's used as the `target=""` for links and forms, among other things, and uniquely identifies the window (or frame or iframe).

You're using the same value each time, so you're reusing the same window for all the URLs.

Use `_blank` as the second argument to make sure you always open a new window, without the risk to reuse an existing one.